# Python-removing a portion of a timeseries with no data to calculate NSE

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to calculate the Nash Sutcliffe Efficiency (NSE) value. The problem I have encountered is that there are gaps in the observation data. And so, I would like to remove simulated data points where the gaps are in the observed to calculate NSE. For example, simulation is from 2020-01-01 to 2020-12-31. However, there are gaps in the observed are from 2020-04-01 to 2020-05-01. How do I remove data from the simulation, so that I am only calculating NSE where both observed and simulated data exists?

```
run_dir = r"C:\data"
stations = ["st1x2"] #station name
obs_data = [r"C:\data\obs.csv"]
sim_data = [os.path.join(run_dir,f"{station}.dat") for station in stations]

obs_df = pd.read_csv(obs_data[0])
sim_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=stations, index=read_dat(sim_data[0]).index.values)

obs_df = obs_df["2020-01-01":"2020-12-31"]
sim_df = sim_df["2020-01-01":"2020-12-31"]

nse = nash_sutcliffe(obs_df["obs1"].values, sim_df["sim1"].values)
```

Right now the NSE is calculated for the entire year of 2020. I would like to calculate NSE from 2020-01-01 to 2020-03-31 and 2020-05-02 to 2020-12-31. Anyone have any suggestions or ideas how I might approach this?

Comment: Minor suggestion: consider defining the NSE acronym. You tagged this question with non-standard evaluation (NSE), but it doesn't seem to be what this question is about.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Artem Sokolov. My question isn't really on the calculation itself but rather how I can use specific timeframes to avoid including gaps. Apologies for the confusion

Comment: HI, are you trying to drop rows where `obs_df["obs1"]` are empty or NaN?

Comment: @Laurent I'm trying to drop rows in `sim_df["sim1"]` as `obs_df["obs1"]` does not have data in April.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess, since you do not provide a reproducible example, but here is how you can remove April values from `sim_df`, assuming the index is **sorted**, using Pandas [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) method:

```py
obs_df = obs_df["2020-01-01":"2020-12-31"]
sim_df = pd.concat([sim_df["2020-01-01":"2020-03-31"], sim_df["2020-05-02":"2020-12-31"]])
```